# How to validate entities in GO?

Tags: go, validation, entity

How to validate in GO?

all results on the internet suggest me to use `github.com/go-playground/validator/v10`

but the problem whenever I pass the struct to another layer or functions, to make sure it is valid, I have to call `validator.Struct()` again and again.

I think about validate directly in the struct (that the way I usually do in c#), to implement it I create a `constructor` for the struct, make all fields private and using getter and setter (the validation logic will be inside the setter and constructor), but the problem is I can not use gorm or mongodb to map entity to table, because all the fields are private and those libs can not read private fields, but if I don't make them private, I can accidently create an struct without using `constructor` or `setter`

how do you deal with entity validation in GO?

Comment: you could make the struct private but have its fields exported. That way people need to call the exported constructor of the package with that private struct, to get an instance of it.

Comment: don't know that way, could you make an example, please?

Comment: ok, give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

You could make the struct private, but have its fields exported. That way, people need to call the exported constructor of the package with that private struct, to get an instance of it.

For example, you have a store package that defines the struct type, but unexported. Additionally, you create an exported constructor.

```
package store

type foo struct { Name string }

func NewFoo(name string) foo { return foo{name} }
```

That way, users of your package, need to call the constructor to get an instance of the struct.

```
package main

import "myorg.com/app/store"

func main() {
  f := store.NewFoo("gopher")
  fmt.Println(f.Name)
}
```

This is not 100% foolproof, as you still can mess up within that store package, and also users of your struct can change the name after calling the constructor.

If you also want to enforce validation via setter, you probably don't get around some kind of helper struct.

---

In my opinion:

Perhaps your idea is too defensive. I am usually fine with validating user input. Within my program, I am not constantly validating myself.

Another thing to consider is that you probably want abstractions and loose coupling. For example, a struct with gorm specific tags, may only be known to your storage layer and not get passed around the entire app. In that sense, your validation could go into `store.CreateUser()` or similar. Perhaps it could also take such a helper struct as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer, about your opinion, I'm curious how can you implement validation well in your code, could I have some example by reading your project on github?

Comment: @phamvu, I dont have many such use cases. At least not on my personal github account.  In my work area such validaton is usually required for things like rest apis, and those are of course owned by my org and not public. However, I might have some examples. [Here is one](https://github.com/bluebrown/kobold/blob/bd3c59b2a13408979163153c2c0b1bec6b429fc9/internal/server/webhooks.go#L45) (codebase could be improved, dont judge^^). This is doing the validation at entry into the application (http endpoint). Once it passed this gate, I am not validating again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use struct validation without using GoValidator you can build your own custom validation. Check the code below:

1 - Define your struct with private fields and validation tags:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    field1 string `validate:"required"`
    field2 int    `validate:"gte=0"`
}
```

2- Create getter and setter methods for each field:

```
func (s *MyStruct) GetField1() string {
    return s.field1
}

func (s *MyStruct) SetField1(value string) error {
    // Validate the value using your custom validation logic or a validation library
    if len(value) == 0 {
        return errors.New("field1 is required")
    }

    // Set the value if it passes validation
    s.field1 = value
    return nil
}

func (s *MyStruct) GetField2() int {
    return s.field2
}

func (s *MyStruct) SetField2(value int) error {
    // Validate the value using your custom validation logic or a validation library
    if value < 0 {
        return errors.New("field2 must be greater than or equal to 0")
    }

    // Set the value if it passes validation
    s.field2 = value
    return nil
}
```

3- Use these getter and setter methods throughout your code to access and modify the struct fields. This ensures that validation logic is always applied when setting values.

```
obj := MyStruct{}
err := obj.SetField1("value1")
if err != nil {
    // Handle validation error
}

err = obj.SetField2(10)
if err != nil {
    // Handle validation error
}

// Access field values
value1 := obj.GetField1()
value2 := obj.GetField2()
```

Comment: OP mentioned getters/setters, in the question, themselves. They found it not feasable as unexported fields are not used by things like gorm. Thats kind of what the question is all about.